# Диапазон покрытия по всему сроку Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Я хочу рассчитать количество прогрессов по выполнению домашних работ в каждом месяце за всю историю (каждый месяц в диапазоне от июня 2018 до февраля 2019 включительно) для каждого курса.
Необходимо учитывать, что прогресс выполнения домашней работы может перетекать из одного месяца в другой (такие прогрессы надо включать в общее число прогрессов для всех месяцев, которые покрывает срок выполнения этих домашних работ).

`progress_id` – `id` прогресса,
`course` – название курса,
`start` – начало выполнения домашней работы,
`finish` – конец выполнения домашней работы.

```py
list_month = ['2018-06', '2018-07', '2018-08', 
              '2018-09', '2018-10', '2018-11', 
              '2018-12', '2019-01', '2019-02']

df_table = pd.DataFrame({'progress_id': ['progress1', 'progress2', 
                                         'progress3', 'progress4', 
                                         'progress5', 'progress6'], 
                         'course': ['course1', 'course2', 'course1', 
                                    'course3', 'course3', 'course4'],
                         'start': ['2018-06', '2018-07', '2018-07', 
                                   '2018-10', '2018-09', '2018-12'], 
                         'finish': ['2018-08', '2018-07', '2018-10', 
                                    '2018-12', '2018-11', '2019-02']
                          }, 
                          columns = ['progress_id','course', 
                                     'start', 'finish'])
```

Попытка сделать добавление новых строк в конец датафрейма ни к чему не привела:   попытка сделать цикл `while df_table['start'] != df_table['finish']` с наращиванием через счетчик значения месяца `'start'` до тех пор пока он не будет равен месяцу `'finish'` и добавление нового "промежуточного" месяца в колонку `'finish'`.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать корректно?

Comment: не могли бы вы привести пример того, что должно получиться в итоге?

Comment: Двойная группировка по курсу и месяцу. Что-то вроде этого: 
df_table.groupby(['course', 'finish'])['progress_id'].count()

Answer (score 2):

```
df_table.groupby('course') \
   .apply(lambda course: \
      course.apply(lambda x: \
               pd.Series(1, index=pd.date_range(x['start'], x['finish'], closed=None, freq='MS')) \
               , axis=1) \
            .sum(axis=0)) \
   .reset_index(level=0).pivot(columns='course', values=0) \
   .reindex(pd.date_range(df_table.start.min(), df_table.finish.max(), freq='MS'), fill_value=np.nan)

course      course1  course2  course3  course4
2018-06-01      1.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
2018-07-01      2.0      1.0      NaN      NaN
2018-08-01      2.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
2018-09-01      1.0      NaN      1.0      NaN
2018-10-01      1.0      NaN      2.0      NaN
2018-11-01      NaN      NaN      2.0      NaN
2018-12-01      NaN      NaN      1.0      1.0
2019-01-01      NaN      NaN      NaN      1.0
2019-02-01      NaN      NaN      NaN      1.0
```

---

Вот немного о том. как это работает

Самый внутренний apply превращает каждую строку в Series вот такого вида

```
2018-12-01  1
2019-01-01  1
2019-02-01  1
```

Внешний собирает их все по курсам

```
course             
course1  2018-06-01    1.0
         2018-07-01    2.0
         2018-08-01    2.0
         2018-09-01    1.0
         2018-10-01    1.0
course2  2018-07-01    1.0
course3  2018-09-01    1.0
...
```

Дальше строим сводную таблицу

В последней строке заполняем возможные пропуски индекса.

Answer (score 1):

Вся программа (после импортов и создания вашей таблицы):

```
df_table["Months"] = 0                    # Добавим новую колонку для количества месяцев

for ind, row in df_table.iterrows():      # Проходим строками таблицы
    start  = row["start"]  + "-01"        # После года и месяца добавим и день в месяце
    finish = row["finish"] + "-01"
    df_table.loc[ind, "Months"] = len(pd.date_range(start, finish, freq="MS")) # см. далее

print(df_table.groupby("course").sum())
```

Вывод:

> ```
>          Months
> course         
> course1       7
> course2       1
> course3       6
> course4       3
> ```

---

**Объяснение:**

Как посчитать, сколько месяцев между (например) `2018-12` и `2019-02` (ваша последняя строка в таблице)?

Так:

1. Построим `DatetimeIndex` с месячной частотой, от первого дня в месяце:

   ```
   In[3]: pd.date_range("2018-12-01", "2019-02-01", freq="MS")
   Out[3]: DatetimeIndex(['2018-12-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-02-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')
   ```
2. Посчитаем, сколько в нем элементов:

   ```
   In[4]: len(_)                 
   Out[4]: 3
   ```

Теперь то же самое с вашей таблицей `df_table`, добавляя вычисленное значение в новый столбец:

```
In[6]: df_table["Months"] = 0

In[7]: for ind, row in df_table.iterrows():
   ...:     start  = row["start"]  + "-01"
   ...:     finish = row["finish"] + "-01"
   ...:     df_table.loc[ind, "Months"] = len(pd.date_range(start, finish, freq="MS"))
   ...: 
In[8]: df_table
Out[8]: 
  progress_id   course    start   finish  Months
0   progress1  course1  2018-06  2018-08       3
1   progress2  course2  2018-07  2018-07       1
2   progress3  course1  2018-07  2018-10       4
3   progress4  course3  2018-10  2018-12       3
4   progress5  course3  2018-09  2018-11       3
5   progress6  course4  2018-12  2019-02       3
```

И наконец применим метод `groupby()`:

```
In[9]: df_table.groupby("course").sum()
Out[9]: 
         Months
course         
course1       7
course2       1
course3       6
course4       3
```

Answer (score 1):

Вся программа (после импортов и создания вашей таблицы):

```
for dt in pd.date_range("2018-06-01", "2019-02-01", freq="MS"):
    new_column = str.format("{}-{:02d}", dt.year, dt.month)
    df_table[new_column] = 0

for ind, row in df_table.iterrows():
    start  = row["start"]  + "-01"
    finish = row["finish"] + "-01"
    dtRange = pd.date_range(start, finish, freq="MS")
    for dt in dtRange:
        colName = str.format("{}-{:02d}", dt.year, dt.month)
        df_table.loc[ind, colName] = 1

print(df_table.sum(numeric_only=True))
```

Вывод:

> ```
> 2018-06    1
> 2018-07    3
> 2018-08    2
> 2018-09    2
> 2018-10    3
> 2018-11    2
> 2018-12    2
> 2019-01    1
> 2019-02    1
> dtype: int64
> ```

---

**Объяснение:**

- *Главная идея:*

  **Как перечислить все месяцы между (например) `2018-12` и `2019-03`?**
  Так что построим объект типа `DatetimeIndex` с месячной частотой, с первого дня в месяце:

  ```
  In[3]: pd.date_range("2018-12-01", "2019-02-01", freq="MS")
  Out[3]: DatetimeIndex(['2018-12-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-03-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')
  ```

*А теперь постепенно.*

Ваша исходная таблица:

```
In[61]: df_table
Out[61]: 
  progress_id   course    start   finish
0   progress1  course1  2018-06  2018-08
1   progress2  course2  2018-07  2018-07
2   progress3  course1  2018-07  2018-10
3   progress4  course3  2018-10  2018-12
4   progress5  course3  2018-09  2018-11
5   progress6  course4  2018-12  2019-02
```

Добавим колонки для всея индивидуальных месяцев в вами требуемом диапазоне:

```
In[62]: for dt in pd.date_range("2018-06-01", "2019-02-01", freq="MS"):
   ...:     new_column = str.format("{}-{:02d}", dt.year, dt.month)
   ...:     df_table[new_column] = 0
   ...:     
In[63]: df_table
Out[63]: 
  progress_id   course    start   finish  2018-06  2018-07  2018-08  2018-09  \
0   progress1  course1  2018-06  2018-08        0        0        0        0   
1   progress2  course2  2018-07  2018-07        0        0        0        0   
2   progress3  course1  2018-07  2018-10        0        0        0        0   
3   progress4  course3  2018-10  2018-12        0        0        0        0   
4   progress5  course3  2018-09  2018-11        0        0        0        0   
5   progress6  course4  2018-12  2019-02        0        0        0        0   

   2018-10  2018-11  2018-12  2019-01  2019-02  
0        0        0        0        0        0  
1        0        0        0        0        0  
2        0        0        0        0        0  
3        0        0        0        0        0  
4        0        0        0        0        0  
5        0        0        0        0        0
```

В цикле для каждой строки таблицы сделаем объект типа `DatetimeIndex` в диапазоне значений в колонках `start` и `finish`, а затем для всякого его элемента в этом объекте запишем значение `1` для соответствующей колонки:

```
In[64]: for ind, row in df_table.iterrows():
   ...:     start  = row["start"]  + "-01"
   ...:     finish = row["finish"] + "-01"
   ...:     dtRange = pd.date_range(start, finish, freq="MS")
   ...:     for dt in dtRange:
   ...:         colName = str.format("{}-{:02d}", dt.year, dt.month)
   ...:         df_table.loc[ind, colName] = 1 
   ...:         
In[65]: df_table
Out[65]: 
  progress_id   course    start   finish  2018-06  2018-07  2018-08  2018-09  \
0   progress1  course1  2018-06  2018-08        1        1        1        0   
1   progress2  course2  2018-07  2018-07        0        1        0        0   
2   progress3  course1  2018-07  2018-10        0        1        1        1   
3   progress4  course3  2018-10  2018-12        0        0        0        0   
4   progress5  course3  2018-09  2018-11        0        0        0        1   
5   progress6  course4  2018-12  2019-02        0        0        0        0   

   2018-10  2018-11  2018-12  2019-01  2019-02  
0        0        0        0        0        0  
1        0        0        0        0        0  
2        1        0        0        0        0  
3        1        1        1        0        0  
4        1        1        0        0        0  
5        0        0        1        1        1
```

Но а наконец применим метод `.sum()`:

```
In[66]: df_table.sum(numeric_only=True)
Out[66]: 
2018-06    1
2018-07    3
2018-08    2
2018-09    2
2018-10    3
2018-11    2
2018-12    2
2019-01    1
2019-02    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: *Я хочу рассчитать количество прогрессов ... для каждого курса.*

Comment: Смотрите мой другой ответ.

Comment: Благодарю! Изучаю код.